# Change icon on leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

based on this question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54651/change-marker-icon-on-click-using-leaflet, i made this :

```
// onEachFeature
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {

        // change icon
        console.log(layer.options.icon);
        e.target.setIcon(myIconReplc);

    });
}

var myIconReplc = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/orange/ambulance.png",
        iconSize: [30,35],
        shadowUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/shadow.png",
        shadowAnchor: [8, 20],
        shadowSize: [25, 18],
        iconSize: [20, 25],
        iconAnchor: [8, 30] // horizontal puis vertical
    }
});
```

And i have this error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

What's wrong ?

--- live : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/pmr/new.php#/carte

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create instance (add `new` before `myIconReplc`), [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html#defining-an-icon-class), like this

```
var myIconReplc = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/orange/ambulance.png",
        iconSize: [30,35],
        shadowUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/shadow.png",
        shadowAnchor: [8, 20],
        shadowSize: [25, 18],
        iconSize: [20, 25],
        iconAnchor: [8, 30] // horizontal puis vertical
    }
});

layer.on('click', function (e) {
   e.target.setIcon(new myIconReplc);
});
```

Comment: thks for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

You've forgot the declare a `new` instance of your `myIconReplc`.

Change:

```
e.target.setIcon(myIconReplc);
```

To:

```
e.target.setIcon(new myIconReplc);
```

If you want to be able to declare an icon without the `new` like most of the classes in Leaflet you can do this:

```
// Normal extending
var MyIconReplc = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/orange/ambulance.png",
        iconSize: [30,35],
        shadowUrl: "../resources/img/map/icons/shadow.png",
        shadowAnchor: [8, 20],
        shadowSize: [25, 18],
        iconSize: [20, 25],
        iconAnchor: [8, 30] // horizontal puis vertical
    }
});

// Shorthand
var myIconReplc = function (options) {
    return new MyIconRepl(options);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var icon = new MyIconReplc();
```

and:

```
var icon = myIconReplc();
```

> You may have noticed that Leaflet objects are created without using the new keyword. This is achieved by complementing each class with a lowercase factory method

See: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class (under Class factories)

Comment: thks for your help and additionnals explanations